# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: transaction underpriced

Tags: erc-20, web3j, android

My contact is already deployed.
Then I am trying to call ERC20 Approve method like

```
val greeting: Future<TransactionReceipt> = greeterErc20.approve(BuildConfig.CONTRACT_ADDRESS_10COLOR, amt).sendAsync()
val transactionReceipt: TransactionReceipt? = greeting.get()
Log.e("transactionReceipt", "" + transactionReceipt?.transactionHash)
```

But getting error message `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: transaction underpriced`

Before that I am calling below method and getting success response.

```
val greeting: Future<BigInteger> = greeterErc20.allowance(Pref.user?.mkey, BuildConfig.CONTRACT_ADDRESS_10COLOR).sendAsync()
val allowance: BigInteger? = greeting.get()
Log.e("allowance", "" + allowance)
```